# Store Images in MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, database, image, facebook, rsrc

I want to know how to store images and files in a MySQL Database.

I want to get images and files like that `www.example/rsrc.php/example-image.jpg`

example on Facebook: facebook-example.com/rsrc.php/v2/yw/r/svhh826BLKd.png

Comment: Storing images in the database is a bad idea. Store references to where they're stored on the filesystem or an object store like Amazon S3.

Comment: I have a social network, and i want to make it like facebook rsrc.php file :) any way, i want to make a CDN for the profile pictures and every picture in my network

Answer (score 14):

Create a BLOB column in database table,

probably  mediumblob.

but it is good to keep the photo in directory and keep the path in the database.  Cheers

```
 CREATE TABLE tblname(ID INT,IMAGE BLOB);

INSERT INTO tblname(ID,IMAGE) VALUES(1,LOAD_FILE('C:/test.txt'));
```

added the answer from the comments to this question in the answer box..

Comment: How do i create that BLOB column table ? :)

Comment: CREATE TABLE tblname(ID INT
                       ,IMAGE BLOB);

Comment: for testing you can insert with this. INSERT INTO tblname(ID,IMAGE) VALUES(1,LOAD_FILE('C:/test.txt'));

Comment: Okay, how to get the photo in php ? the photo were placed in the DB ?

Comment: suppose this is ur html tag  and want to display image database using PHP. hope it hepls. <img src="get.php?id=1"/> <?php

  $id = $_GET['id'];
  // do some validation here to ensure id is safe

  $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
  mysql_select_db("dvddb");
  $sql = "SELECT image FROM photos WHERE id=$id";
  $result = mysql_query("$sql");
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  mysql_close($link);

  header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
  echo $row['image'];
?>