# How to display default image if particular image is not available in database?

Tags: php, mysql

How to display the particular image in case if that image is not available in database? I have

1. database name:project
2. table name: image
3. fields: id (int), file (varchar) [image url stored here], name (varchar) [image description]

PHP code is here:

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("no connection ");
mysql_select_db("project")or die("no database exit");
echo "<h2 align='center'>Displaying image from database</h2>";
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM image");
echo "<table>";
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";echo $row["id"];echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>"; ?> <img src="<?php echo $row["file"]; ?>" height="100px" width="150px">    <?php echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";  echo $row["name"]; echo "</td>"; 
    echo "</tr>";   
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: We stopped using this API a long time ago. Join us.

Comment: Yeah save yourself lots of trouble and use PDO before you spend too many hours developing and have to change it all later.

Comment: check my answer it will work if image not exists in the destination

Comment: @ris can you completely insert your code in my file . I am not getting actually where i should put that piece of code.

Comment: I've removed the external link from this question - we try to discourage question posters from asking readers to fetch stuff. Please add whatever was in that link to your question - you can use the code formatting tool if it is console output. (External links like file lockers and paste boards are a bit more acceptable in comments, but it is still better if the question just contains everything).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

simply use `@getimagesize` description [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) this method will check if image actually exists . will return false if image deleted from db or from destination.

```
<? 
$img="image url"; //orginal image url from  db 
if(!@getimagesize($img))
{
    $img="default image"         //if image not found this will display
 }

?>
```

**Update**

for your code use like this

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("no connection ");
mysql_select_db("project")or die("no database exit");
echo "<h2 align='center'>Displaying image from database</h2>";
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM image");
echo "<table>";
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
     $img=$row["file"]; //orginal image url from  db 
    if(!@getimagesize($img))
    {
        $img="default image"         //if image not found this will display
     }

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";echo $row["id"];echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>"; ?> <img src="<?php echo $img; ?>" height="100px" width="150px">    <?php echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";  echo $row["name"]; echo "</td>"; 
    echo "</tr>";   
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you brother it work as expected :) Here is output https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9wWzdgPkqb_ajh6blJ5X2RsSVU/edit?usp=drivesdk

Answer (score 4):

Use a simple if condition

```
<img src="<? php if($row["file"]){ echo $row["file"] ; } else{// other image name}?>" height="100px" width="150px">
```

Comment: Thanks for the logic it works for only null image field .It do not work for the file that is deleted from database  .Here is screenshoot https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9wWzdgPkqb_eTlPOUpmX1k3Nk0/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: yes it wont work. though u delete the file,  records are available in database.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ternary operator to do this, refer below and give a try

```
    <?php
        $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("no connection ");
        mysql_select_db("project")or die("no database exit");
        echo "<h2 align='center'>Displaying image from database</h2>";
        $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM image");

        echo "<table>";
        while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
 // USE TERNARY OPERATOR HERE
        $imagePath = (isset($row["file"]) && !empty($row["file"]) && file_exists($row["file"]))?$row["file"]:'img.default.jpg'; // REPLACE YOUR IMAGE PATHE HERE
               echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>";echo $row["id"];echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>"; ?> <img src="<?php echo $imagePath; ?>" height="100px" width="150px">    <?php echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";  echo $row["name"]; echo "</td>"; 
            echo "</tr>";   
        }
        ?>
        </table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but it do not work at all ,Default image override all actual file also .Here is screenshoot https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9wWzdgPkqb_U2NGZk9SNXN5a0E/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: It still do not work for file that is deleted from server .here is my screensoot https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9wWzdgPkqb_cmtNRGRYRmZnYmM/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: If file deleted from server wont you update database image path? Anyway try my updated code

Comment: No,bro my application won't update database once having particular image due to this  reason i need default image

Comment: Anyway try my updated code, I modified it. But, it will be good approach to update database when you modify the file.

Answer (score 1):

You're storing the directory to the image within the varchar? if so try changing your database to store the image itself using BLOB as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18769978/store-images-in-mysql-database)

Then you can use an if statement.

```
<img src="<? php if($row["file"]){echo $row["file"];} else { echo '/directory/to/image.jpg'}?>" height="100px" width="150px">
```

I would also recommend using a include, this may not be 100% relevant for your current project but can help down the line when needing to use more than one database connection.

1. create a dbconnect.php file //name it what ever you want
2. insert code into dbconnect.php file:

`<? php $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("no connection"); mysql_select_db("project")or die("no database exit");?>`

3. in any file you're trying to use a database use `include_once 'dbconnect.php'`

Answer (score 1):

If the file reference in the database is pointing to a file that may have been deleted, you have to check if the file still exists. Ideally, when he file is deleted, the reference in the database should be updated too, to avoid such problems, but that may not always be possible, especially when many people have access to FTP.

Check to see if file exists:

```
if(file_exists($yourImage)){
echo $yourImage;
}
else{
echo $defaultImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php if($result["image"]==""){
         $path='upload/blankphoto.png';
         }
         else 
        {
            $path="upload/".$result['image'];
            }?>

    <img src="<?php echo $path?>" height="100" width="100">
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you add a bit of text about what this code does and how it solves the problem the OP identifies?